# How do I only get one x-axis-value on WPF Chart control

Tags: wpf, charts

I get a new value on x-axis for each line in the Chart. I only need the first (or last) value on the x-axit from the chart line or better, it only show month 1-12.

```
  LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
  lineSeries.DataPointStyle = dataPointStyle;
  lineSeries.DependentValuePath = "Indextal";
  lineSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Dato";

  lineSeries.IndependentAxis = new DateTimeAxis
  {
    Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
    Location = AxisLocation.Bottom,
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months
  };
  //((DateTimeAxis)lineSeries.IndependentAxis).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

  lineSeries.ItemsSource = IndsætGrafData(år);
  chart_LineSeries.Series.Add(lineSeries);
```

The picture show the result I get. I only need 1 date of each month.
[image: There are to many dates]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you create `DateTimeAxis` 2 times. Move the construction of this axis to the constructor like this, so that it is created only once:

```
private DateTimeAxis _xAxis;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._xAxis = new DateTimeAxis
    {
        Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
        Location = AxisLocation.Bottom,
        IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months
    };

    chart_LineSeries.Axes.Add(this._xAxis);

    // ...
}
```

Then change the code where you set the axis:

```
lineSeries.IndependentAxis = this._xAxis;
```

Comment: I understand what you want, but when I try it gets worse. See my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Vorrtex, when I tried your answer, I get this result:
[image]

Here are some more code, maybe it can help?

```
private DateTimeAxis _xAxis;

public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();

this._xAxis = new DateTimeAxis
{
    Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
    Location = AxisLocation.Bottom,
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months
};

chart_LineSeries.Axes.Add(this._xAxis);
}


void GrafListe()
{
  label_Info.Content = "";
  chart_LineSeries.Series.Clear();
  aktiekursListe = controller_Aktiekurs_Database.HentAltFraAktiekursTabellen(idVirksomhedensStamdata);

  if (aktiekursListe.Count() > 0)
  {
    datoListe = controller_Dato.HentAlleDatoer();
    chart_LineSeries.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    var myYear =
      from a in aktiekursListe
      join d in datoListe on a.IdDato equals d.Id
      orderby d.DagTid descending
      select new { d.DagTid.Year };

    int[] antalÅr = new int[myYear.Distinct().Count()]; 
    int antal = 0;
    foreach (var item in myYear.Distinct())
    {
      antalÅr[antal] = item.Year;
      antal++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < antalÅr.Count(); i++)
    {
      GrafData(antalÅr[i]);  
    }
  }
  else
    label_Info.Content = "xx";
}




void GrafData(int år)
{
  Style dataPointStyle;
  dataPointStyle = GetNewDataPointStyle(år); 

  LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
  lineSeries.DataPointStyle = dataPointStyle;
  lineSeries.Title = år.ToString();
  lineSeries.DependentValuePath = "Indextal";
  lineSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Dato";
  lineSeries.ItemsSource = IndsætGrafData(år);
  chart_LineSeries.Series.Add(lineSeries);
}
```

Comment: You didn't add the line `lineSeries.IndependentAxis = this._xAxis;` to your `GraphData` method as I told you in the last paragraph of my answer. Also it is correct that the green chart is before the red one because they have different years, and 2011 is before 2012. IF you want only 12 months, you can use CategoryAxis.